# Weird bug (header) when using the glossaries package and KOMA's automark

Tags: glossaries

I'm using

```
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
```

in my preable together with the glossaries package.

Whenever I use an acronym within a `\section{...}` command, I get a header like the one pictured below. Any ideas how to prevent this? I'm using LuaLaTeX btw.

[image]

Comment: What version of `glossaries` are you using? Have a look at [I get an error when using a glossary entry in a chapter/section heading or caption](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#movingarg). If that doesn't help, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, add a minimal example, otherwise it will be impossible to help you.

Comment: IC. I'm using the latest versions from the MiKTeX Project, but it seems like this behavior is actually caused by the hyperref package. Anyways, your answer helped me to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Adding to my comment to remove this from the unanswered list.)

Summarising from [I get an error when using a glossary entry in a chapter/section heading or caption](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#movingarg), it's generally not a good idea to use commands like `\gls` or `\glslink` in chapter or section titles:

1. If you have a table of contents, the relevant line in the TOC will
   also have a link to the glossary, and the entry's page list will
   include the table of contents page. (Same applies for `\caption` and
   the list of figures/tables.)
2. If you are using a page style that adds the chapter/section title to the page header, then each page header for that section will generate a link to the glossary. (Pre version 4.0 can also cause weird results in the header when the `sanitize` option is in use.)
3. If you are using the [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package, you can end up with a nested link in the table of contents and you will also cause a problem for the bookmarks.

It is therefore better to use the non-link creating commands, such as `\glsentrytext` instead of `\gls`. For example:

```
\section{\glsentrytext{sample}}
```

or for an acronym:

```
\section{\glsentryshort{sample}}
```

or

```
\section{\glsentrylong{sample}}
```

Note that for this to work with the PDF bookmarks, `\glsentrytext{sample}` or `\glsentryshort{sample}` or `\glsentrylong{sample}` must be fully expandable. If not, you'll need to use `\texorpdfstring` to supply an alternative for the bookmarks. (The uppercasing commands like `\Glsentrytext` *aren't* expandable.)